# React-Avatar-Editor basic example no working

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**PROBLEM:**

I'm trying to make React-Avatar work using React(1.6+) and TypeScript(latest).
I've been running into multiple issues through the implementation, as I can't seem to find a Typescript version of the JSX based on the [**demo**](https://github.com/mosch/react-avatar-editor/tree/master/docs).

**Expected:**

I expect it to *just* work, when having typings for the project and its dependencies set up. I've had to manually change a bunch of things to make webpack build the package, but I can't make it work.

**Actual:**

Errors everywhere. Currently I'm getting this:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `MyEditor`.
    in MyEditor

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

**Code:**

**avatarUploader.tsx:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import AvatarEditor from "react-avatar-editor"; 

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AvatarEditor
        image={"http://example.com/initialimage.jpg"}
        width={250}
        height={250}
        border={50}
        color={[255, 255, 255, 0.6]} // RGBA
        scale={1.2}
        rotate={0}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default MyEditor
```

**fileItem.tsx:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom"; 
import MyEditor from "./../avatarTest/avatarUploader" 

    ReactDOM.render(
        <MyEditor />
        ,  
        document.getElementById("body")
    );
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",

    entry: {
        filemanager: "./src/fileItem/fileitem.tsx", 
        avatarTest: "./src/avatarTest/avatarUploader.tsx"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name]/[name].bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist/transpiled-components/"
    },

    watch: true,
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [   
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
            { test: /\.tsx$/, loader: "babel-loader!ts-loader" }
        ],
    }, 
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM" 
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Added  **[SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/xj2w90v67o)**

Comment: I don't see your build configuration, so it's difficult to help. An example at codesandbox with your `webpack.config` would help. Also have a look at Flow.js as this should be prefered for React apps - see this [post](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/01/13/typescript-vs-flow) for more details.

Comment: Updated with a sandbox link. Paths may be incorrect on files, but it should give you an idea. Webpack builds fine, though.

The only difference between my Webpack.config.js and the one used in the demo is that I use ts-loader, whereas they seem to use babel...